# Query first column with the same data on the second column

Tags: mysql

```
ID | Name
---|-----
1  | John
2  | John
3  | Mike
4  | James
5  | Doe
```

I have this table. I want to query so that I'd be able to get this:

```
12 John
3 Mike
4 James
5 Doe
```

i've tried it with putting the variables with array but the result is only 12345 Doe. Will anybody please give me an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID), NAME
    FROM DB.TABLE
    GROUP BY NAME
```

Comment: That is great of you. -_- Thank you very much sir.